# Can't watch Udemy on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: video, error-handling

I tried many ways like:
Install "Gstreamer plugins from the bad set",
Installing ubuntu-restricted-extras,
Toggle DRM,
Turn of Use hardware acceleration,
Install FFmpeg. But nothing works. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a web browser, a media player, other? What does it say in the "system check page"? Supposedly it should list the requirements...

Comment: @xralf given that this post is for 20.04 and 18.04 is beyond standard support I would not think your bounty is going to get any solutions that work for the end of support release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the developer pack for FFmpeg? After installing [`libavcodec-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libavcodec-dev) you should be able to watch the videos and hear the audio correctly:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-dev
```

This works for Firefox and Edge. It should work for other browsers as well

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had all the necessary codecs already installed. Instead I needed to enable DRM:
https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023851591-How-do-I-view-DRM-protected-content

> Enabling Widevine
> Widevine is disabled by default after installation. It can be enabled or disabled at any time by toggling of the component in brave://settings/extensions (Menu → Settings → Extensions → Widevine):
> [image]